# Magento can't get level 3 categories

Tags: category

I have been trying to get children categories from certain category. And recently i discovered that some child categories are not displaying. After several hours of trying to figure out what's wrong. I found that in MySQL database those categories not displaying who has column level equal to 3. Witch is fine because my category tree is:

```
Root
--PublisherParent
---Publisher
```

And what is strange that when i set level to 0 in Mysql database in `catalog_category_entity` table, categories start to display...
My code is:

```
$publisher_cat_id = 13;
$subPublishers = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($publisher_cat_id)->getChildren();

$publisher_names = array();
foreach(explode(",",$subPublishers) as $item)
{
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($item);
    array_push($publisher_names,$_cat->getName() . "," . $_cat->getUrl());
}
```

Anyone had this issue?
Please let me know if you know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**getChildren()**

- `function only give active categories`
- `It is provide only sub categories not sub subcategories.`

If you **want to get  all sub categories then use** :`getChildrenCategoriesWithInactive()`;

**Also want to all child level categories then try below code:**

```
$subPublishers=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('path', array(
    array('like' => '%'.$publisher_cat_id.'%'), //spaces on each side
    array('like' => '%'.$publisher_cat_id), //space before and ends with $needle
    array('like' => $publisher_cat_id.'%') // starts with needle and space after
));
```

Comment: Well i need the second code to work because getChildrenCategoriesWithInactive(); gives me those categories that has level 3. I did't mentioned that i have imported those categories with magmi. So i have alot of categories that has level 0 there.

The second code gives me all of categories from publisher category and alot not from the publisher category.

Comment: Managed to fix it by using your code and modifying publisher category id it like this:
$publisher_cat_id = "1/3/13/";

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
<?php 

        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2);
        $subCategory=($category->getResource()->getChildren($category, true));
        foreach ($subCategory as $categoryID)
        {
                $sCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryID);
                $catnames = array();
                foreach ($sCategory->getParentCategories() as $parent) {
                    $catnames[] = $parent->getName();
                    /* Do Something here */
                }
                echo  implode('>>',$catnames);
                echo '<br>';

        }
?>
```